# What is the difference between "git remote add origin", " set-url origin" and config...?

Tags: git

There seem to be at least 3 ways to do what sounds as the same thing.

```
# 1. git remote add origin https://x@bitbucket.org/x/y.git
# 2. git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/x/y.git 
# 3. git config --local remote.origin.url ssh://git@bitbucket.org/x/y.git
```

- **What are their differences?**
- What is the preferred or standard way?

Note: This may seem as a duplicate of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830557/git-remote-add-origin-vs-remote-set-url-origin) but those answers are incomplete and do not explain the difference of changing the URL vs the "remote"?

**EDIT:**

Doing some further googling: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20928583/1147688) SO answer:

> A `remote` in git is basically a bookmark for a different repository
>   from which you may wish to pull or push code. The bookmarked
>   repository may be on your local computer in a different folder, on
>   remote server, or it may even be the repository itself... but the
>   simplest analogy is a bookmark. The repository doesn't even have to be
>   a version of your repository, it may even be a completely unrelated
>   repository.

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22712683/1147688):

> `origin` is **not** the remote repository name. It is rather a local alias set as a key for the remote repository URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `git remote` command is meant for manipulating (working with, adding, and removing) *remotes*.  It has ten (!) sub-commands:

1. `git remote add`
2. `git remote rename`
3. `git remote remove`
4. `git remote set-branches`
5. `git remote set-head`
6. `git remote get-url`
7. `git remote set-url`
8. `git remote show`
9. `git remote prune`
10. `git remote update`

Each sub-command may have its own sub-sub-commands or options; and if run with no sub-commands at all, `git remote` simply lists all remotes.

For whatever reason, you are asking about only two of the ten sub-commands: `add` and `set-url`.  This may be because you are not sure what a *remote* is in the first place.  The short answer is that a *remote* is just a name, but it's a name that is *used* to keep track of another Git repository, at some other URL.

While `origin` is a pretty standard remote name, it's not the only possible remote name—and your own repository may have *no* remote, in which case `origin` is not the name of one of your remotes, since you have none.

Still, many if not most repositories have exactly one remote, because so many are created by `git clone`.  The `git clone` command *automatically* creates one remote, which it names `origin` unless you tell it to use some other name.  So most repositories already have a name `origin`.

#### `git remote add`

What `git remote add` is for is to add a *new* remote.  If you have one remote now, and you add another, you will then have two remotes.  If you have none, and add one, you will have one.

Again, the point of a remote is to name another Git repository, and that other Git repository is going to be found at some URL.  Hence, to make a remote useful, it needs a URL.  So `git remote add` takes two arguments: the name of the *new* remote to add, and the URL to associate with that name.

(This omits a lot of the fancier special things you can do with remotes.  I've never found some of them useful myself, but they are the reason that there are a bunch of option flags to `git remote add`.)

#### `git remote set-url`

What `git remote set-url` is for is, mainly, to *change* the URL associated with some *existing* remote.  Hence it takes the name of an existing remote, and a new URL.  The default action is to remove the old URL and insert the new one instead.

Git tries not to limit you to a single URL here: it allows *more than one* URL to be attached to each named remote.  Precisely what happens when there are multiple URLs for any one remote is a bit tricky; it's best not to do this until you are comfortable with single-URL remotes.

#### `git config`

The `git config` command is a much lower level thing.  Most of the settings you can make or change in Git are ultimately done through *configuration entries*, and this includes adding or deleting remotes and changing the URLs associated with any one particular remote.  What this means is that the higher level `git remote` command often translates into one or more low-level `git config` operations.  If you know precisely which configuration entries control which remote(s) in which ways, you can use `git config` to achieve some of the same things that `git remote` does.

Some of the things `git remote` can do are not merely configuration settings, so not everything is translatable like this.  But adding or deleting a remote, and changing its URLs, *are*, and therefore *can* be.

Adding a new remote essentially consists of running two `git config` commands.  If the name of the remote is *R*, the two configuration items are `remote.R.url` and `remote.R.fetch`.  Setting the first without setting the second is not a great idea in general, and you need to know what to set the second *to*, so it's safer to use `git remote` to add a new remote.

Changing the (single) URL for an existing remote consists of running just *one* `git config` command.  For remote *R*, that's `git config remote.R.url new-url` (`--local` is the default for `git config` so you may omit it).  The URL does not affect the `fetch` value, so it is safe (albeit a bit pointless) to use `git config` to do this instead of using `git remote` to do it.  If there *is* more than one URL attached to some particular remote name, though, `git remote` adds safety checks that `git config` totally bypasses.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Not so Different but they are different*

Actually When you run `git remote add origin git@github.com:User/TestRepo.git`, then a new remote created named *origin*.

When you run `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/TestRepo.git`,git searches for **existing** remote having the same name *origin* and change it's remote repository url, but if git unable to find any remote having name origin, It will raise an error fatal: `No such remote 'origin'`.

Answer (score 0):

In first case, when you run `remote origin some@github.com/User/repo`, you create a new remote, which name is `origin`

In two other cases git is searching for an existing remote, which names are `origin`
There is no preferred way for these examples, because commands make different things.

Comment: So `origin` is just an alias? Does that mean I can write: `git config --local remote.mybucket.url ssh://git@bitbucket.org/x/y.git`, given that I have added `mybucket`?

Comment: That's a good question. I'd like to know the answer to that one also. Perhaps @not2qubit you can post this as its own question?